# chipmunk and codeblocks undefined reference error

Tags: c, codeblocks, chipmunk

I built chipmunk with the codeblocks project file and have linked to the libchipmunk.a file but I am still getting 1 error when trying to built the hello world sample file.

Undefined reference to 'cpBodySetPos'

Any body know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you write #include"chipmunk.h" in the code where you are calling the cpBodySetPos?

Answer (score 0):

Its either you haven't linked the libchipmunk.a file properly in the linker tab or if it an older version of chipmunk, then the generated `libchipmunk.a` file does not contain the declaration/definition of the `cpBodySetPos()`.

To link `libchipmunk.a` file:

- Open the project file.
- Then right click on the project (from the left pane) and click "Build Options."
- In the window, on the left there should be , Release, Debug.
- Select your project name, then click on the "linker" tab.
- From there, add the library into link libraries.
- If you're using windows, you'll have to manually find the library, or in linux, just type "chipmunk" and gcc/ld should do the rest for you.

Also do refer [this link](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-freebasic/source/browse/trunk/support/README.txt?r=109) to find out if you are generating the `libchipmunk.a` file properly for codeblocks and from the latest version of chipmunk.